# Owner folders are not sync in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I'm the owner of a folder in Dropbox.

When I change a file in this directory, the other members get updates and notifications.   However, when another member changes something in the same direcory, my file system is not updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be the client properties.
Setting my machine as administrator solved the problem.